# Multiple services in one assembly. How installer knows which service to install and start?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, service-installer

I have a project which includes 2 windows services. I create a ProjectInstaller to install these items, which works fine. But I have a question; given the code defined below, how does the project installer know which service to install for serviceInstaller1 and which for serviceInstaller2?

Is it simply based upon the ServiceName?

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller2;
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            serviceInstaller1 = new ServiceInstaller();
            serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "xxx";
            serviceInstaller1.Description = "Does Something";
            serviceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

            serviceInstaller2 = new ServiceInstaller();
            serviceInstaller2.ServiceName = "yyy";
            serviceInstaller2.Description = "Does something else";
            serviceInstaller2.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller1);
            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is based on `ServiceName`.

Installer doesn't really care about the name, you can supply pretty much any name and installer will be happy to register a Windows service with this name for you, but when you attempt to start service it will fail, unless it finds service in your assembly that has `ServiceName` matching to the `ServiceName` specified in the installer.

```
Error 1083: The executable program that this service is configured to run in does not implement the service.
```

Comment: Just a further question, when deploying with only one service, I am assuming the name doesnt matter, as it simply installs the first service it finds. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mick Walker - If you have one service in the installer, and you supply one or more services to `ServiceBase.Run()` method, the first service in the collection will be used despite the service name.

Comment: What if I need to create two services from one assembly with different credentials?